# Strange CSS Behavior on <input type='image' /> and <input type='button' />

Tags: html, css

If I do the following, I notice that `<input type='image' />` adds the border to the input, which makes sense because you want the image to fit. But check out that space at the top, it looks like that's a bug.

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0; background:#000;
}
body{
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
.cartpal{
  width:544px; height:64px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;
}
#to_cart,#paypal{
  background:#eee; border:2px solid #007; font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-radius:30px;
}
#to_cart{
  width:200px; height:64px; 
}
#paypal{
  width:306px; height:60px;
}
#to_cart:hover,#paypal:hover{
  border-color:#fff;
}
#to_cart:active,#paypal:active{
  border-color:#fc3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
    <title>Is this a Bug?</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='cartpal'><input id='to_cart' name='to_cart' title='Add to Cart' type='button' value='Add to Cart' /><input id='paypal' name='paypal' title='Pay with PayPal' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!' type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/silver-pill-paypalcheckout-60px.png' /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After a simple change to from `<input type='image' />` it works as expected. Can't be the white space. It's been removed.

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0; background:#000;
}
body{
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
.cartpal{
  width:544px; height:64px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;
}
#to_cart,#paypal{
  height:64px; background:#eee; border:2px solid #007; border-radius:30px; font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:0;
}
#to_cart{
  width:200px;
}
#paypal{
  width:306px; background:url(https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/silver-pill-paypalcheckout-60px.png);
}
#to_cart:hover,#paypal:hover{
  border-color:#fff;
}
#to_cart:active,#paypal:active{
  border-color:#fc3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
    <title>Is this a Bug?</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='cartpal'><input id='to_cart' name='to_cart' title='Add to Cart' type='button' value='Add to Cart' /><input id='paypal' name='paypal' title='Pay with PayPal' type='button' /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is another behavior I don't fully understand.

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0; background:#000;
}
body{
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:980px; margin:0 auto;
}
.cartpal{
  width:544px; height:64px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;
}
#to_cart,#paypal{
  height:64px; background:#eee; border:2px solid #007; border-radius:30px;
}
#paypal{
  width:306px; background:url(https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/silver-pill-paypalcheckout-60px.png);
}
#to_cart{
  width:200px; font:bold 20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#to_cart:hover,#paypal:hover{
  border-color:#fff;
}
#to_cart:active,#paypal:active{
  border-color:#fc3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
    <title>Is this a Bug?</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='cartpal'><input id='to_cart' name='to_cart' title='Add to Cart' type='button' value='Add to Cart' /><input id='paypal' name='paypal' title='Pay with PayPal' type='button' /></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I did was only set the `font` on `#to_cart`. Since the default font-size is even smaller, why is `#paypal` now a pixel or 2 from the top? Would not the half-leading on a smaller font be less?

I can do a work arounds, that's not the issue. I'm really just trying to understand why my first and last example exhibit this strange, chaotic behavior. What's the logic? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify, what space are you talking about?

Comment: Did you hit the `Run code snippet` buttons? It should be super clear.

Comment: To make the question more clear, he is trying to align `type="button"` and `type="image"` next to each other.

Comment: `display: inline-block` introduces space between elements. chekcout this [link](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: It's not because of the `display`. All web designers must know that one or more white spaces and/or line breaks in HTML create a single white space, with the exception of preceding and succeeding line breaks, within block level Elements. I've remove the white space within `.cartpal` to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your Inputs floating to align in row. Just change your css:

```
#paypal, #to_cart {
height: 62px;
background: #eee;
border: 2px solid #007;
border-radius: 30px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: the important part is the float left

Comment: No. `inline` Elements don't need to be floated to remain `inline`. My work around does make them `display:block; float:left;`. I'm really asking why this is happening, not looking for a work around. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser provide some sort of default implementation to some elements,
Like in your case because of default styling provided by the browser...

**input="button"**
[image]

**input="image"**
[image]

Notice addition `1px` of `padding` to `top` and `bottom`, because of default appearance rule by rendering engine of your browser.

```
input[type="button" i],
input[type="submit" i], 
input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    padding: 1px 6px;
   }
```

here you can see addition padding is applied by browser for `input="button"` but the same dont exist for `input="image"`

[More about appearance](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

Comment: Are you not aware that padding is included for `<input />`s, with the exception of `<input type='image' />`? I made the `padding:0;` just to test your explanation, but it did not work. The code is now included in the 2nd example. Thanks for trying though.